# Is there no provision for WSDL validation in WSO2 esb?

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

Like other ESBs(like Tibco), is there no provision in WSO2 Esb to validate the request first  based on the wsdl provided in the proxy services.

Comment: do you mean schema validation(xsd) of messages?

Comment: yes...  The data types and all..

Comment: you can validate again xml schema using a mediator.

Comment: Validate Mediator is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use validate mediator : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Validate+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is there. While creating proxy (I have done with custom proxy) you can use publish WSDL option. It will validate the request format against WSDL. Apart from that, you can add resources as well like XSDs if you want to validate data type, mandatory elements over there before entering inside in sequence.
Hope it will help.

Comment: I have added the WSDL but it does not validate the request against the schema defined in the WSDL...
I think I will have to use the Validate Mediator as suggested in the above posts.

Comment: Yes, validate mediator can be used once message is entered into 'in/out sequesnce'.